# Nested while loops in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm having a big issue with some nested while loops I have in my java program. From what I have debugged my code checks the second while loops statement once, then exits the loop forever. I have no clue why this is happening so I will post the code here:

```
while (current != null) {
        if(id == current.getMovie().getId()) {
           movieExists = true;
           movie = current;
           while (checkCurrent == movie) {
              showingPointer = checkCurrent.getMovie().getLinkHead();
              while (showingPointer != null) {
                 if (cal.compareTo(showingPointer.getShowing().getShowingCalendar()) == 0) {
                    return false;
                 }
                 showingPointer = showingPointer.getNext();
              }
              checkCurrent = checkCurrent.getNext();       
           }        
        }
        current = current.getNext();
     }
```

Comment: For a better answer please tell us the definition of checkCurrent and movie. I think the problem is in the checkCurrent == movie

Comment: checkCurrent and movie are both nodes in a linked list storing movie objects. I did what techExchange said but to no avail. It still oddly skipped over the while loop. Going directly from the while (checkCurrent == movie) { line to the checkCurrent = checkCurrent.getNext(); line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This statement

```
while (checkCurrent == movie) {
```

compares object reference and always false . This is not the way to compare two instances

you might want to change the code to compare values something like

```
 while(checkCurrent.getMovie().getId() == movie.getMovie().getId()){
```

Or have a equals() implemented to compare.

More on [Equals](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2002/10/equalhash.html)

Comment: They are nodes in a linked list would this answer still apply?

Comment: yes it will apply, its about basic object compharison

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are coming to the line return false when you execute the code.If the return statement is getting executed, it will immediately return from the method

Comment: Well like I said the method never reaches that point. It tries the statement in THAT while loop (the second one) and never tries it again and just ends the loop

Comment: When you are debugging,at what line your loop is breaking?

Answer (score 0):

Why `return false`? This is not a correct method in breaking a loop. Use `break` instead.

Comment: i'm not breaking the loop I'm returning false to another method...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `while (checkCurrent == movie)` you should use a `Comparator` interface in your Node class and override its `compare` method and then compare your objects. As `==` compares object reference's so it wont work in your case.